# How to avoid generation of empty attributes in XSLT?

Tags: xslt

I have written XSLT file with the following code:

```
<xsl:attribute name="subCode">
    <xsl:value-of select="Field[@key='XY']"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

Let's say that my INPUT XML looks like this:

```
[...]
<Field key="XY"/>
[...]
```

In this case my XSLT would generate the following output:

```
<SomeElement subCode="">
[...]
</SomeElement>
```

My question is: How to ged rid of empty attribute `subCode=""`?

I know that it is possible by using some conditional instruction like `<xsl:if>`, however, this seems to be an ugly solution (because I have thousands of similar attributes generated in my XSLT).

It must be done in the same XSLT. I cannot add post-processing in additional XSLT file.

Besides that, the output XML has got its XSD Schema defined. And the schema says that this attribute is **optional**. Maybe there is some way to apply that XSD schema for the output XML?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete solution that is the shortest and most precise from all answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <someElement>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="attr"/>
  </someElement>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Field[@key='XY' and not(.='')]" mode="attr">
    <xsl:attribute name="subCode">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<t>
 <Field key="XY"/>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result (no attribute at all is generated) is produced**:

when the source XML document is this:

```
<t>
 <Field key="XY">1</Field>
</t>
```

**the same transformation again produces the correct, wanted result;**

```
<someElement subCode="1"/>
```

Comment: +1 This is correct: testing for element' string value. Other predicates would be `[string()]` and `[normalize-space()]`.

Comment: @Alejandro both of the predicates you propose will return `false()` for the string `"0"`

Answer (score 1):

You can define a template to match the attribute which will give you the correct output for a missing `@key` but if you also add the predicate `[.!='']` it should then also ignore the attributes with no value.

```
<xsl:template match="@key[.!='']">
  <xsl:attribute name="subCode"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Or in your example if you only want the `@key='XY'` matches use:

```
<xsl:template match="@key[.='XY']">
  <xsl:attribute name="subCode"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

**Edit:** Here is a more complete example that I used to test this.

Source XML

```
<Fields>
   <Field key="XY">A</Field>
   <Field key="XY">B</Field>
   <Field key="">C</Field>
   <Field>D</Field>
</Fields>
```

Accompanying XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <output>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Field">
  <xsl:element name="NewField">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@key[.='XY']">
  <xsl:attribute name="subCode"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result

```
<output>
  <NewField subCode="XY">A</NewField>
  <NewField subCode="XY">B</NewField>
  <NewField>C</NewField>
  <NewField>D</NewField>
</output>
```

Comment: I don't think the OP is asking for attribute' string value, but element' string value.

Comment: Ah yes, I misunderstood the question a little!

Answer (score 0):

You should apply the following templates to your attributes:

This template matches all **key** the attributes who's value is 'XY':

```
<xsl:template match="@key['XY']">
    <xsl:attribute name="subCode">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

This template matches all the **key** attributes with a (text)value longer than 0:

```
<xsl:template match="@key[string-length(.)]">
    <xsl:attribute name="other">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

And finally this template matches all the attributes (*) that are empty:

```
<xsl:template match="@*[not(string-length(.))]" />
```

So if you have an input like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root>
    <Field key='v'>One</Field>
    <Field key='XY'>Two</Field>
    <Field key='a'>Three</Field>
    <Field key='v'>Four</Field>
    <Field key='XY'>Five</Field>
    <Field>Six</Field>
    <Field>Seven</Field>
    <Field key='b'>Eight</Field>
    <Field key=''>Nine</Field>
    <Field></Field>
    <Field key='x'>Eleven</Field>
    <Field key=''>Twelve</Field>
    <Field lat='x'>Thirteen</Field>
</Root>
```

You can generate an output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<Root>
    <SomeField other="v">One</SomeField>
    <SomeField subCode="XY">Two</SomeField>
    <SomeField other="a">Three</SomeField>
    <SomeField other="v">Four</SomeField>
    <SomeField subCode="XY">Five</SomeField>
    <SomeField>Six</SomeField>
    <SomeField>Seven</SomeField>
    <SomeField other="b">Eight</SomeField>
    <SomeField>Nine</SomeField>
    <SomeField/>
    <SomeField other="x">Eleven</SomeField>
    <SomeField>Twelve</SomeField>
    <SomeField>xThirteen</SomeField>
</Root>
```

using the following xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Root>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </Root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Field">
        <xsl:element name="SomeField">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@key['XY']">
        <xsl:attribute name="subCode">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@key[string-length(.)]">
        <xsl:attribute name="other">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@key[not(string-length(.))]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, you put a lot of effort in your answer. However, I feel that I didn't put clearly what I want to achieve. What I want is simply skip generation of empty attribute.